# How to add a third party library to android studio project from github?

Tags: android, git, android-support-library

I want to use this library in my project.

[Github - AndroidCountryPicker](https://github.com/roomorama/AndroidCountryPicker)

for other git libraries i always found the build gradle statement provided to be added to the project, here it is not.
Can anyone help me?
like these dependencies which i add to the project.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.floatingmenu:floatingmenu:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.4.3@aar'
    compile 'org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.4.0@aar'
    compile('com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary-v0.5.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/AndroidCountryPicker-master.jar')
}
```

If anyone could help me how to use the camera library would be great.

Comment: `compile files('libs/AndroidCountryPicker-master.jar')` this line looks correct. Do you have that jar ?

Comment: @Blackbelt No i don't, i have downloaded the download zip file from the link and copied in to my libs folder. that is al i have. i m on a urgent need for this. help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

This library is build with Eclipse and doesn't provide a gradle support.

Also this lib has some resources, then you can use a jar file.

Remove `libs/AndroidCountryPicker-master.jar` and remove this line from your `build.gradle`:

```
compile files('libs/AndroidCountryPicker-master.jar')
```

You have to:

- Clone this library locally as a module in your project. Therefore clone the 
  https://github.com/roomorama/AndroidCountryPicker/tree/master/CountryPicker folder in your `root/library1` folder.

You should have somenthing like:

```
root:
      library1
        build.gradle
      app
        build.gradle
      settings.gradle
```

- Change your `settings.gradle` file in

  `include ':library1'
  include ':app'`

In your `app/build.gradle` file you have to add:

```
dependencies {
    // Module Library
    compile project(':library1')
}
```

Finally in your `library1/build.gradle` you have to add something like this:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


    android {
         lintOptions {
              abortOnError false
          }

        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
          targetSdkVersion 22
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }              
        }
     }

     dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     }
```